# Laravel 4: Garbage value in URL after Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-routing

I am passing parameter via Redirect and I am getting a garbage value in the URL.

Example: localhost/feeds/%7Busername%7D

Garbage value: %7Busername%7D

::ROUTE::

```
Route::get('feeds/{username}', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'feeds', 'uses' => 'FeedsController@getFeedsPage'));
```

::CONTROLLER::

```
<?php
  class FeedsController extends BaseController {
    public function getFeedsPage($username) {
      return View::make('feeds.index')
      ->with('username', $username);
    }
  }
```

::REDIRECT::

```
$username = User::where('id', '=', $id)->pluck('username'); // Returns username (eg. john.doe) - I checked
return Redirect::route('feeds')
->with('username', $username);
```

Issue: Instead of passing john.doe, I'm getting %7Busername%7D

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 return Redirect::route('feeds')
->with('username', $username);
```

to

```
return Redirect::route('feeds', $username);
```

Comment: I did try changing it. Still the same problem.

I am getting (localhost/feeds/%7Busername%7D) instead of (localhost/feeds/john.doe).

Comment: I tried passing direct value as a parameter.
return Redirect::route('feeds', 'john.doe');
Still I am getting (localhost/feeds/%7Busername%7D).

I guess there is no problem in Redirect.

I also tried passing direct value in the Controller.
return View::make('feeds.index')->with('username', 'michael.sangma');
Still I am getting this %7Busername%7D.

I also tried typing (localhost/feeds/john.doe), it works fine. The page loads perfectly. But, the problem is. I don't know why, it doesn't work when I am redirecting to the page. Even passing direct value in the Controller is not working.